# Não consigo commitar do meu GitHub desltop para o meu GitHub

Tags: git, github

Está a confirmação do usuário, porém não consigo colocar. Alguém pode me ajudar a como fazer isso?
[image: Está aparecendo isso]

Comment: exatamente o que tá escrito. rode o git config para o seu email e seu nome. eu uso o email e nome de usuario do github.

Answer (score 1):

Na leitura do erro já está escrito o que você precisa fazer.
Nesse [link](https://mazer.dev/como-configurar-username-e-email-por-projeto-com-git/) tem um tutorial de como fazer isso.
Dentro do Git, executar os dois comando com as suas credenciais:

```
git config --global user.name "Seu nome"
git config --global user.email "seuemail@gmail.com"
```

Recomendo que sempre procure na internet sobre o erro, pois isso ajuda você a ter um perfil investigativo e também te ajuda muito na sua aprendizagem.

Comment: Obrigado pelo conselho!
:)

Comment: De nada, se a reposta está correta e resolveu seu problema marca a resposta como aceita.